# Скрыть часть текста если ее длина превышает ее ширину

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Скрыть текст получается, однако все идет не как надо: даже если текст скрывается, то его ширина остается такой же выталкивая блок справа, тем самым возникают проблемы с адаптацией.
Если задавать ширину в px то все тоже идет не по плану, возникает путаница при адаптации.

```css
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.item{
  width: 200px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
h6{
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width:calc(100% - 32px);
}
.circle{
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  background:#ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="item_title">
        <h6>One step closer to the edge, and im gotta break</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задайте `width:calc(100% - 32px);` родителю `h6`, так как у Вас не определена ширина для `.item_title` поэтому она равна 100%, и h6 считает свою ширину относительно 100%, а не 200рх, как Вы хотели

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item_title">
        <h6>One step closer to the edge, and im gotta break</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">1</div>
</div>
```

```
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.item{
  width: 200px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.item_title{
  width:calc(100% - 32px);
}
h6{
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.circle{
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  background:#ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 32px;
}
```